# Why I can't search for UUID in elasticsearch database using filters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have `Django` app which use `elasticsearch` database, I use `elasticsearch-dsl` and all my filters and queries works. But I have a problem with one parameter, it's UUID. I always got 0 results from my request in `shell`:

```
s = Search(index='my_index_name').filter('term', UUID='0deaa49b-15b6-4c10-acb7-d98df800e0df')
response=s.execute()
response
```

I use `django-rest-elasticsearch` and I have the same issue, I got correct `REST` result with all my filters, but not with UUID request. Something like this works, but I need to use filtering.

```
q = Q("multi_match", query="0deaa49b-15b6-4c10-acb7-d98df800e0df", fields=["UUID",])
    response=s.execute()
    response
```

Maybe someone know hot to use UUID  in my `REST`, because `UUID=0deaa49b-15b6-4c10-acb7-d98df800e0df` don't work.

Comment: What is the mapping for the field `UUID`? Does it retrieve the document if you change the term to `_all`?

Comment: Are you talking about term in filter()? Dsl has'n something like _all value. `UnknownDslObject: DSL class _all does not exist in query`. Can u explain what did you mean when ask about UUID mapping?

Comment: What is the mapping for your UUID term in ElasticSearch? What data type do you have it set as, what analyzers are you using for it etc?

Comment: I just indexed UUID as a field from tsv, it has `Text()` type.Indexing: `def indexing(self) : obj = ElementIndex( UUID=str(self['UUID']), )`. ElementIndex: `class ElementIndex(DocType): UUID = Text()`

Comment: This is because your ID field is analyzed. All fields that has type text by default analyzed. You need to specify "not_analyze" property on your field. Or you can specify field _id in term query.